# Specific Range in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a pivot table in excel with vba. Now I have to group some different rows.
For Example A1, A6, A19 ...

The information which rows should be grouped are on an own Worksheet where I read from.
When I create an new string which contains for example: groupString = "A1, A5, A90, A103"
and then I use `Worksheets("TableTest").Range(groupString).Group` I always get an Runtime Error that I cannot group multiple selections.

When I use `Worksheets("TableTest").Range("A1, A23").Group` it works, but I need the groups which
I read from the other Worksheet. Thanks for helping.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you use `Worksheets("TableTest").Range("A1, A23").Group`, A23 falls out of pivot and only A1 is considered.

Range.Group documentation states that range must specify a single cell.

Have you tried grouping cell by cell?

```
For Each cell in Worksheets("TableTest").Range(groupString).Cells
    cell.Group
Next
```